# How to reproduce locally a timezone issue happening in the test suite on CI?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, circleci

Some tests in a Ruby on Rails test suite I'm working with fail on CI (the team uses CircleCI) consistently after 8pm ET, which corresponds to midnight UTC.

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on my machine, which is in the CET timezone (so the issue happens after 2am local time).

- The CI machine is set to use UTC everywhere, but I imagine there's a layer of the framework that overrides this and sets a different timezone.
- I tried changing the time and timezone of my Mac to 8pm ET, reopening Terminal (confirming with `date` that it's after 8pm ET) and running RSpec, but the tests pass.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: can you show an example of the failing test? You can set timezone of your app in `config/application.rb` --->  `config.time_zone = 'Rome'`,
`config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc`
and see what happens. To retrieve CI machine timezone try to print a line that shows it: 
`Time.zone.name # => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.now`

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to ensure that you have the same time zones on your CI environment as you have localy, just like @Joe suggested.
Also ensure that you specify which time zone is used, both in your tests and in your code.

```rb
def bad_time_compare
  timestamp > Time.current
end

def better_time_compare
  timestamp > Time.zone.current
end
```